# creating moment-timezone object properly

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to create a moment-timezone object with custom hour and minute, however I keep getting invalid date error.

```
var momentz   = require('moment-timezone');

var now   = momentz().tz('Europe/Istanbul');
var year = parseInt(now.format('YYYY'));
var month = parseInt(now.format('M'));
var day = parseInt(now.format('D'));
var hour = 8;
var minute = 30;
var newdate = momentz([year,month,day,hour,minute,0]);
```

Validation returns false

```
console.log(newdate.isValid());
```

What am I missing here? Thank you.

Comment: can you put this in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: I'm not sure about how to run a node js code on jsfiddle. However I fixed the problem with `parseInt(now.format('M')) -1;`

Answer (score 0):

There is no separate "moment-timezone object".  Moment-timezone augments the moment object.  Therefore, you should just call your variable `moment`, not `momenttz`.  This is [from the docs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/node-js/):

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
```

Then to do what you asked:

```
var m = moment.tz('Europe/Istanbul'); // get the time in Turkey
m.startOf('day').hour(8).minute(30);  // set the hour and minute
```

Note the use of `startOf('day')`, which is easier than setting seconds and milliseconds to zero separately.

You could also just write this as one line:

```
var m = moment.tz('Europe/Istanbul).startOf('day').hour(8).minute(30);
```

Regarding the code you wrote in you question - the `format` function shouldn't be used for getting individual parts.  There are separate functions for those, `.year()`, `.month()`, `.date()`, etc.  In particular, recognize that since the `format` function is locale-specific, you will see months numbered 1-12, while as integers with the `month` function or in the array you built, they are expected to be 0-11.  Additionally, when you constructed `newdate`, you didn't keep any time zone information, so the result is in the *local* time zone.